# Seaborn example to plot with date on the X axis not showing dates

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am executing this code from [this page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and it is not working as expected.

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd; plt.close("all")

index = pd.date_range("1 1 2000", periods=100,
                      freq="m", name="date")
data = np.random.randn(100, 4).cumsum(axis=0)
wide_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, ["a", "b", "c", "d"])
ax = sns.lineplot(data=wide_df)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

The X axis is not displaying dates.

[image]

I am using these versions:

```
seaborn==0.10.0
pandas==0.25.0
matplotlib==3.2.0
```

How to plot with dates on X?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on my system, running your code without changing anything:

[image]

I obviously have a different default figure size and style, but that is not the issue. You should upgrade to the latest version of Pandas. There was a major new release earlier this year.